# Making jQuery Waypoints Offset Relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

You know how scroll position is usually retained when refreshing a webpage?

Well, jQuery [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) offset feature appears to use this page position as 0 instead of the actual top of the page.

For example, given a waypoint offset of 50, let's say you're currently at a scroll position of 1000 when the page refreshes. The refreshed page will automatically jump back to 1000. This waypoint won't active until the scroll position reaches 1050.

**Is it possible to keep the waypoints relative to the top of the page?** So even if the page is automatically updated a scroll position of 1000 a waypoint with an offset of 50 will be active.

```
$('.thing').waypoint(function(direction) {
    // do stuff
}, { offset: 50 })
```

More elaborate code:

```
(function($, window, document) {

    $(function() {

        var $popularArticles = $('.popular').find('article'),
        $latestArticles = $('.latest').find('article');

        var $latestPost = $latestArticles.filter(':first');
        var $latestPostDate = $latestPost.find('time').text();

        $latestPost.before('<h2>' + $latestPostDate + '</h2>');
        $popularArticles.filter(':first').before('<h2>Popular Now</h2>');

        // updates postdate in latest h2

        $latestArticles.waypoint(function(direction) {
            var $postDate = $(this).find('time').text();
            if (direction === 'down') {
                $latestH2.text($postDate);
            }
        }, { offset: 102 }).waypoint(function(direction) {
            var $postDate = $(this).find('time').text();
            if (direction === 'up') {
                $latestH2.text($postDate);
            }
        }, { offset: function() {
            return - $(this).height() / 2 + 50;
            }
        });

        // h2 waypoints

        var $latestH2 = $('.latest').filter(':first').find('h2'),
            $popularH2 = $('.popular').filter(':first').find('h2');

        $popularH2.add($latestH2).waypoint('sticky', { offset: 50 });

    });

}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the browser doesn't jump to the scroll position until after  the page has loaded, so try running your waypoint code before the page loads instead of when it loads.